# Window.close() is working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have written a javascript function to pass the value from child window to parent window and in the child window on clicking the close button I am calling the below function which closes the window on chrome. but the same function is not working in firefox. kindly let me know what can I do to close the child window in Firefox.

```
function SetName() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = jq('#sizemsg').html();
        }
        window.close();
    }
```

Comment: what console says?

Comment: I have done this in my project which is working fine for both chrome and Firefox.i done like this `window.opener.location = '/path';window.close();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try self.window.close(), as chrome autoamtically checks for window type child/parent, but Firefox strictly follows rules ..